# How to split large *.csv files with headers in Bash?

Tags: bash

I need split big *.csv file for several smaller. Currently there is 661497 rows, I need each file with max. 40000. I've tried solution that I found on Github but with no success:

```
FILENAME=/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/my_file.csv
HDR=$(head -1 ${FILENAME})
split -l 40000 ${FILENAME} xyz
n=1
for f in xyz*
do
    if [[ ${n} -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo ${HDR} > part-${n}-${FILENAME}.csv
    fi
    cat ${f} >> part-${n}-${FILENAME}.csv
    rm ${f}
    ((n++))
done
```

The error I get:

```
/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/download.sh: line 23: part-1-/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/my_file.csv.csv: No such file or directory
```

thanks for help!

Comment: please update the question and expand on what you mean by *`but with no success`* ... error? empty files? missing header from each file? something else?

Comment: consider enabling debug mode (`set -xv)` and run the script again, then review the debug output; rough guess is that `part-${n}-${FILENAME}.csv` generates something other than what you're expecting (hint: what's the value of `FILENAME`?)

Comment: note the name of the directory/file in the error message ===>>> `part-1-/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/tyre_8.csv.csv` ... is that what you really expected?

Comment: I don't understand why in error there is double file extension, if in path I remove the extension, error still exist. But the file path is correct, works for other things in my *.sh file.

Comment: the double `.csv` is due to `$FILENAME` containing a `.csv` and then in your code you've appended an extra `.csv` on the end of `$FILENAME` ... hence `tyre_8.csv.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind `FILENAME` contains both a directory and a file so later in the script when you build the new filename you get something like:

```
part-1-/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/tyre_8.csv.csv
```

One quick-n-easy fix would be split the directory and filename into 2 separate variables, eg:

```
srcdir='/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files'
filename='tyre_8.csv'

hdr=$(head -1 ${srcdir}/${filename})
split -l 40000 "${srcdir}/${filename}" xyz
n=1

for f in xyz*
do
    if [[ ${n} -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo ${hdr} > "${srcdir}/part-${n}-${filename}"
    fi
    cat "${f}" >> "${srcdir}/part-${n}-${filename}"
    rm "${f}"
    ((n++))
done
```

**NOTES:**

- consider using lowercase variables (using uppercase variables raises the possibility of problems if there's an OS variable of the same name)
- wrap variable references in double quotes in case string contains spaces
- don't need to add a `.csv` extension on the new filename since it's already part of `$filename`

Comment: Thank u! Now it's partially working :) There is one new file, but has 0kb. Error: 'cat: /home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/xyz*: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/cnf/domains/cnf.com.pl/public_html/sklep/dropshipping-pliki/products-files/xyz*’: No such file or directory'

Comment: @D_P ah, sorry, got the `xyz*` mixed up with the `*.csv` ... I've updated the answer

Comment: Works! New files are created, great! But I have two questions: 1). I still get errors like 'rm: cannot remove ‘xyzal’: No such file or directory', and 2). can we wrap new files in separate folder for tidiness? :)

Comment: re: the `rm` error ...  does it happen for all of the `xya*` files or just some? I'd recommend some basic troubleshooting ... get list of `xyz` files before entering the `for` loop, perhaps echo "######## $(wc "$f")"` as first line in loop to show filename and details on size of file; note: I'm assuming your actual script is identical to what's shown here; define a new variable (eg, `tgtdir=/new/directory`) and change the two target file locations to `"${tgtdir}/part-${n}-${filename}"`

Comment: if you're still having problems I suggest a) upvote and/or accept this answer if it answers your original question and b) consider asking a new question to address any new issues you're running into

Comment: For now you helped mi a lot for my purposes, so thank u very much!